# Checking for equivelance

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, underscore.js, gmaps4rails

OK, I'm missing something here and I just can't seem to find it because the logic seems correct to me, but I'm certain I'm not seeing the error.

```
var VisibleMarkers = function() {
var filtered = _.reject(Gmaps.map.markers, function(marker) {
  return marker.grade != $('.mapDataGrade').val() && !_.contains(marker.subjects,$('.mapDataSubjects').val())
  });
return filtered
}
```

I'm using underscore.js and jQuery to simplify my javascript work.

So right now, I'm checking by means of selects which data gets to be rejected and then I display the filtered markers on the (google) map (if it helps at all, this is using gmaps4rails which is working perfectly fine, its this bit of javascript that's making me lose the last of the hairs on my head).

Currently, the code functions 100% correctly for the ".mapDataGrade" select, but the ".mapDataSubjects" isn't.  Now the markers object has a json array of the subjects (this is for students) and each item in the array has its ID.  Its this ID that I am supposed to be checking.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

If there's more info that needs to be included, please let me know.

This is on plain javascript on a RoR application using gmaps4rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the markers object has a json array of the subjects (this is for students) and each item in the array has its ID. Its this ID that I am supposed to be checking.

`_.contains` compares a values, but it sounds like you want your iterator to compare a value to an object's "id" property.  For that, [`_.some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) would work; it's like `contains`, except that, instead of comparing values, you can write the comparison as a function:

> Returns true if any of the values in the list pass the iterator truth test.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
!_.some(marker.subjects, function(subject) {
    return subject.id == $('.mapDataSubjects').val();
})
```

If I'm right, the whole line should be like this:

```
return marker.grade != $('.mapDataGrade').val() && 

    // check that none of the subjects is a match
    !_.some(marker.subjects, function(subject) {

        // the current subject is a match if its ID matches the selected value
        return subject.id == $('.mapDataSubjects').val();
    });
```